# how to resolve the error in the face detection project

Tags: python

face detection Error  File "C:\Users\Mahesh_1\Desktop\face_Recognition\face_detector.py", line 7, in 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-o3uk2uiw\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
added snapshot of code install the required openCV package

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put valid image name. look at your imp_img variable which .jpg loaded file. Which is not valid file name.